# Programmatically move in the direction camera is facing

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mapkit, geo

I'm trying to move a user position marker in the direction the camera is facing. Kind of like you would control a character in a game.
Since camera in MapKit is aligned north, I thought for moving forward I'd add some latitude degrees and then rotate the resulting point on camera angle.

I have some converters from meters to how many degrees is that:

```
class Converter {
  fileprivate static let earthRadius = 6378000.0 // meter

  class func latitudeDegrees(fromMeter meter: Double) -> Double {
    return meter / earthRadius * (180 / Double.pi)
  }

  class func longitudeDegress(fromMeter meter: Double, latitude: Double) -> Double {
    return meter / earthRadius * (180 / Double.pi) / cos(latitude * Double.pi / 180)
  }
}
```

So for moving forward, my code looks like this:

```
let latitudeDelta = Converter.latitudeDegrees(fromMeter: speed)
let y = userLocation.latitude + latitudeDelta
let x = userLocation.longitude
let a = -self.mapView.camera.heading * Double.pi / 180
self.userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: x*sin(a) + y*cos(a), longitude:x*cos(a) - y*sin(a))
```

I've tried different approaches, and none seem to work. Is there something fundamentally wrong? Could it be that I also need to consider Earth curvature in the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

After some more struggling, I found out that this problem is called "Direct Geodesic Problem". [Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) I found all the formulas I needed, but in the end used a great [C library](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io).